# Logback is unable to show trace id or thread id when updated to 1.2.10

Tags: logging, log4j, logback, slf4j, logback-classic

The library project for logging functionality was using logback with slf4j api for logging. I was able to get thread id in log messages before I updated log4j version in my project (which is dependent on logging library project)
As soon as  I added log4j 2.17.1 version, trace id/ thread id was missing from logs. The logging library project is configured with slf4j api and logback.

> 2022-03-25 15:41:00.318 DEBUG 80093 — [executor] c.s.b.d   : ODaySt(d5142ded-7b38-440e-96c4-100a3ed2d42f) **[fb308aa8a20a97b9]** BEFORE:    aClient.invoke(table.tableInfo,s-p-c.ct.gov:080,COLLEGE,null,0,3fe8cba2-3ff-b849-8c67-9665)

> 2023-02-02 11:45:41.728 DEBUG 60127 — [Executor] c.s.b.d   : jon(1422d82d-dc67-4b52-a0ee-416b95c9205d) BEFORE:    bClient.invoke(table.tableInfo,t.unx.com:080,_va_CARS_06423-c48c-40e4-a5af-be032_23_ge100,null,0,5bc76fbd-19681-5a5151036d15)

I tried reverting the changes but unable to fetch the threadid